# Python: Replace a string starting from a charecter

Tags: python, string, replace

I need an **optimised** way to replace all trailing characters starting from a '/' in a string.

For example:

```
mytext = "this is my/string"
```

i want a result like this

```
mytext = "this is my/text"
```

only the string after '/' must be replaced and must be done in optimised way. can anyone find a solution for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be fastest:

```
s = "this is my/string"
mytext = s[:s.rindex('/')] + '/text'
```

What I've tested:

```
>>> s = "this is my/string"
>>> pattern = re.compile('/.*$')

>>> %timeit pattern.sub('/text', s)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 730 ns per loop

>>> %timeit s[:s.rindex('/')] + '/text'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 284 ns per loop

>>> %timeit s.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/text'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 321 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you mean by optimized but i'd do:

```
>>> import re
>>> mytext = "this is my/string"
>>> re.sub('/.*','/text',mytext)
'this is my/text'
```

Answer (score 0):

Reg.exp. are slow, since you need all the text after the (first?) `/` character, the best way to do this is:

```
mytext[:mytext.index('/')+1] + 'the replacement text'
```

This will fail if you don't have '/' however.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how fast it is, and no error checking, but I'd find the slash and combine strings.

```
s = 'this is my/string'
result = s[:s.find('/')+1]+'text'
```